# OpenSSL create pfx certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

I have create .pem file from .cert file using the below line in openssl.exe :

`OpenSSL> x509 -inform der -in C:\Certificate\Binary_Certificate_245568.cer -out C:\Certificate\Binary_Cert.pem`

It worked without any issues.

Then when I try to generate the pfx file from .cert and .pem file using the following statement I get error:

```
OpenSSL> pkcs12 -inkey C:\Certificate\Binary_Cert.pem -in C:\Certificate\Binary_Certificate_245568.cer -export -out C:\Certificate\SGS_VS_CERT.pfx

unable to load private key
34359836736:error:08064066:object identifier routines:OBJ_create:oid exists:crypto/objects/obj_dat.c:698:
34359836736:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:
error in pkcs12
```

Can anyone please advise what I am doing wrong as I need to generate .pfx file. Thanks

Comment: `-in` should be _PEM-format_ cert (your `Binary_Cert.pem` not `Binary_Certificate_245568.cer`). `-inkey` should be your **private key** not any kind of certificate in any format. Also, it looks like you may have some spurious or duplicate OID definition in your config file, check that; it is at envvar `OPENSSL_CONF` if set and otherwise in `openssl version -d`. Especially check if you are using a config file meant for a different version of OpenSSL, such as an earlier version before an upgrade. PS: this is not a programming or development issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow steps given below in order to create .pfx certificate by combining the external CA issued server(.cer), intermediate(.cer) and root(.cer) certificates into one file (.pfx) on redhat linux server using openssl tool :

A) To run below command for generating the CSR in linux using openssl tool -

> [user@machine]$ openssl req -new -nodes -newkeys rsa:2048 -keyout myapp.mydomain.com.key -out myapp.mydomain.com.csr -sha256

Note : -nodes means 'NOT TO USE DES ALOGORITHM' and create multiple backup of this key file, which will be used again during certificate renewal.

B) To generate .pfx ( certificate chain sequence to be SERVER-CER --> INTERMEDIATE-CERT --> ROOT-CERT ) in linux using openssl.

- SERVER-CERT myapp.mydomain.com.cer
- INTERMEDIATE-CERT myintermediatecert.com.cer
- ROOT-CERT myrootcert.cer
- KEY FILE myapp.mydomain.com.key

STEP 1 - To combine all certificates in one pem certificate(myapp.mydomain.pem) using command 'cat' in redhat.

> [user@machine]$ cat myapp.mydomain.com.cer myintermediatecert.com.cer myrootcert.cer > myapp.mydomain.com.pem (output pem cert)

STEP 2 - To convert PEM to PFX by importing the private key with password configured.

> [user@machine]$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out myapp.mydomain.com.pfx -inkey myapp.mydomain.com.key -in myapp.mydomain.com.pem

Note : you will get an option to set the password to output .pfx file.

STEP 3 : To verify .pfx file using openssl by entering the password.

> [user@machine]$ openssl pkcs12 -in myapp.mydomain.com.pfx -info